# Sniffing HTTP messages using scapy

Tags: http, networking, scapy, payload

I'd like to sniff and identify, let's say HTTP GET messages. Obviously, I need to use `sniff()` for this purpose and filter to `tcp and port 80`. Furthermore, suppose I'd like to extract some HTTP header. That could be done through analysis of the payload.

My problem is that this alone isn't a bulletproof solution as with a sheer luck a payload of some TCP packet can start with the format of an HTTP message.

I guess the probability to encounter with this kind of packet is significantly small.

Do you think one should handle this possibility? If so, how?

P.S
I'm not interested with using `scapy-http` library.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t really get the issue. If the port is 80, you are 100% sure that it’s HTTP so you don’t have

> some TCP packet can start with the format of an HTTP message.

Because it is said to be HTTP... A simple

```
def handle(pkt):
    # this is a nice HTTP packet
    http = pkt[Raw].load
sniff(filter=“tcp and port 80”, prn=handle)
```

Will do the trick. Doesn’t it ?

Comment: Okay, so maybe I'm missing something, but: Consider the scenario of sending a big file through HTTP. We might look at a TCP packet which it's Raw is only payload, right? And so, it might be that *the payload* itself magically contains somehing looks like an HTTP message.